# Remove item in array and synchronize the view with the state of react and react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I would like to know how can I have the correct display when I remove an item in array.

Currently, I have this :

[image]

in my state :

[image]

When I remove the second item "test 2", I have this on display :

[image]

and in my state :

[image]

How can I have the real render please ("test 1" and "test 3") ?

On my component I have this :

```
{replies.map((reply, indexReply) => {
return (
    <tr key={indexReply}>
        <td className="text-center">
            <input className="input-quick-reply-text" type="text" maxLength="20" defaultValue={reply.text} onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeText(e, indexReply)}/>
        </td>
        ...
        <td>
            <div className="text-right">
                <div className="circle-button remove-reply" onClick={() => this.deleteItem(indexReply)}>
                    <FontAwesomeIcon icon="minus"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
)
})}
```

My function in my class component :

```
deleteItem = (indexReply) => {
    this.props.removeReply(this.props.indexBucket, this.props.indexBlock, indexReply);
};
```

In my reducer :

```
case SEQUENCES.REMOVE_REPLY :
        indexBucket = action.indexBucket;
        indexBlock  = action.indexBlock;
        indexReply  = action.indexReply;

        console.log(indexBucket, indexBlock, indexReply);

        return {
            ...state,
            buckets: state.buckets.map((bucket, i) => i === indexBucket ? {
                ...bucket,
                blocks: bucket.blocks.map((block, i) => i === indexBlock ? {
                    ...block,
                    messages: block.messages.map((message, i) => i === 0 ? {
                        ...message,
                        replies: [
                            ...state.buckets[indexBucket].blocks[indexBlock].messages[0].replies.slice(0, indexReply),
                            ...state.buckets[indexBucket].blocks[indexBlock].messages[0].replies.slice(indexReply + 1)
                        ]
                    } : message)
                } : block)
            } : bucket)
        };
```

I tried to add "this.forceUpdate();" in my deleteItem function but i have the same problem...

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debuging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why using array indexes as key is [not recommended](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/no-array-index-key.md).

You're using the array index as the key prop in your table rows, that way if you have an array like `["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"]` and you update the state to make it become `["test 1", "test 3"]` the `key` prop for `"test 3"` is still the index 1 so React renders the previously rendered DOM elements with key 1 instead of the new one for performance reasons. A quick fix is to change `<tr key={indexReply}>` to `<tr key={reply.text}>`